# wordpress JSON.parse syntax error

Tags: php, json, wordpress, parsing

In the DB, 'imgs_urls' field:

```
["http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/120.jpg","http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/222.jpg"]
```

php:

```
$images_urls = get_post_meta($user_post, 'imgs_urls', false); //return array
$a = json_encode($images_urls);

<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $id; ?>urls" id="<?php echo $id; ?>urls" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
```

and now the big crap output when the page load:

[image]

Obviously, after in my js, I have an error when Im trying to do:

```
var images = $.parseJSON($("#"+imgId+"urls").val());
```

---

### edit

Now if I start with the js in a function that is executed when the page is loaded:

```
var vv = [];
vv.push('http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/118.jpg');   
vv.push('http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/118.jpg');
$("#" + imgId + "urls").val(JSON.stringify(vv));
```

after the post is saved, in the DB:

```
["http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/118.jpg","http://localhost/wordpress-gallery/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/118.jpg"]
```

exactly the same DB format and this time no error message with:

```
var images = $.parseJSON($("#"+imgId+"urls").val());
```

I'm using the same php json_encode function...weird, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the quotes. One thing you can do is take the HTML version of the JSON:

```
$a = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($images_urls));

//JavaScript:
var images = $.parseJSON($("<div/>").html($("#"+imgId+"urls").val()).text());
```

Explanation:

```
$("<div/>").html($("#"+imgId+"urls").val()).text()
```

This is to get rid of the HTML entities (i.e. `$lt`) in `$("#"+imgId+"urls").val()` that we got from `htmlspecialchars`. We only want to parse that when parsing the JSON.

Comment: I'm still having the parse error but at least the output is much better: value="["[\"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress-gallery\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/01\/122.jpg\",\"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress-gallery\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/01\/224.jpg\"]"]" .I dont need the decodeURI function, all I want to do is to put each url string in the html image source tag...

Comment: @Frank Reload the page, I was wrong about `decodeURI` (I misread the documentation). Try the new method.

Comment: this is suppose to be straight foward...look at the edit part, thanks by the way

Comment: @Frank You set the `div`'s *value*, you didn't add it as an attribute. In that case, the fact that there are quotes won't matter.

Comment: ok but did you try your code? That does not work for me, have you a jsfiddle example?